# Should you use ros::Subscribe or message_filters::Subscribe?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I was browsing different github repositories I came accross these two type of way to write a node in ros. Why do people use these two and which one is preferable ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400012/should-you-use-ros::subscribe-or-message_filters::subscribe-?/) by [tomkimsour](https://answers.ros.org/users/73888/tomkimsour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-05-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ros::Subscribe` is the standard way to subscribe to a topic.

`message_filters::Subscribe` can be used when you need to sync two or more topics. For example an RGB and a Depth image from a Kinect like camera. You can use `ApproxSync` or `ExactSync` depending on your specific application.

---

Originally posted by [Alex-SSoM](https://answers.ros.org/users/86099/alex-ssom/) with karma: 163 on 2022-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

did you read the entries to the specific documentation for both (http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters and http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29). I mean for my understanding you can use both and it's fine.

---

Originally posted by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) with karma: 28 on 2022-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1